# Ajax.BeginForm that can redirect to a new page without submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have something like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Validate", "Basket", new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "panelId", 
        HttpMethod = "Post", 
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        OnSuccess = "SuccessMethod" 
    }))
{
    @if(Model != null)
    {
       my action...
    }
    else
    {
     Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"))
    }
}
```

It works perfect when I use submit button, because partial is refreshing, and layout stay the same.

I have a problem, when my `Model` became `null`, because user make a remove action on my page. Then I want to make redirect to my home page (different layout), but when I do that (like in my code), I get two layounts on my page, because of `InsertionMode.Replace` mode.

How can I omit the Ajax.BeginForm in my view?

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'I get two layouts on my page'? Any error?

Comment: My page with `Ajax.BeginForm` use `Layout1`, but Index use `Layout2`. Because of `InsertionMode.Replace` I get my Home page with Layout2 in Layout1 (I have two header banners, one from Layout1, one from Layout2).

Comment: what does your SuccessMethod look like?

Comment: @JamieD77 
if (result.url) {
        window.location.href = result.url;
    }

But this is fire only after submit button click. In my case, redirect depends on Model value.

Comment: i guess you should post more code like your controller actions.  I'm having trouble understanding why you cant check the `Model == null` in your controller and redirect instead of loading this view in the first place

Comment: @JamieD77 On my page, when I have Ajax.BeginForm I have also another actions, like remove Order button. When user remove last order I want to redirect whole page to Home/Index. This remove button is not connected with submit, so not connected with ActionMethod from BeginFrom as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using an ajax form (`Ajax.BeginForm`) the framework overwrites just the form, giving you the two layouts when you redirect from within the ajax form (as only the html within the form is redirected, the rest of the page outside the form is not redirected).

You can get around this with some javascript/jquery:

First, remove the `Response.Redirect`

This can be replaced by a placeholder div to indicate no results, or the code can check if there were no results - without more code, it can't be determined if/how this would be done in your specific case, so in the general case, add a placeholder, eg:

```
@if (Model == null)
{
    <div class='nomodel'></div>
}
```

Second, update the OnSuccess code inside `SuccessMethod()` to check if there's no model (or check if there are no order rows), then redirect the entire page, eg:

```
if ($(".nomodel").length > 0) {
    location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home"))'
}
```